# Get only thumbnail from the viewfinder instead of whole photograph in javaME

Tags: java, video, java-me, mobile, symbian

I have an application in JavaME that can display the feed from viewfinder using the VideoControl

```
Item videoItem = (Item)vidc.initDisplayMode(VideoControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE, null);
```

and take a snapshot using the appropriate method. However, I don't wish to capture the whole photo, but just the thumbnail from the viewfinder instead. The data is feeded to the device's display, so they are there somewhere. But can I get the raw data that can be seen in the videoItem instead of calling the getSnapshot method, that already introduces some encoding, needs permissions and takes a lot of time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no way to do this.  The viewfinder's image isn't available to you except through `getSnapshot()`, which as you said is not instant due to encoding and permissions.

The fact that the viewfinder is being fed directly to the device's display means it can be implemented natively far more quickly than passing the encoded bytes to Java.

If you specifically need a thumbnail size image, you'd need to perform manual resizing of the image returned by getSnapshot().